# Infinite Loope ARSCNView anchor(for node: SCNNode) -> ARAnchor? when Node NOT in Scene

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am trying to return a previously created node in my Session Delegate:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else {return SCNNode()}

    let anchorNode = sceneView.anchor(for: earthNode)

    if anchorNode == nil || anchorNode == planeAnchor {
        return earthNode
    }

    return nil
}
```

I am trying to see whether there is already an anchor assigned to my node, and if not, return earthNode.

My problem is that `let anchorNode = sceneView.anchor(for: earthNode)` is either freezing, or infinite looping.

My working theory is that this is due to the fact that `earthNode` isn't yet placed in the scene.  But that seems like a wonky explanation.  I also, of course, presume that my usage of ARkit reeks of ignorance.

Comment: Updating as I fiddle with this:  Adding `earthNode` as a child to the `rootNode` doesn't help, still loops, or freezes.

Comment: I haven't solved the question above, but realized I was doing it all wrong anyway.  What I came up with to assign my `earthNode` to the first detected plane is the following:

Comment: `    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let _: ARPlaneAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else {return}
        
        if node.childNode(withName: "earth", recursively: false) == nil {
            node.addChildNode(earthNode)
        }
    }`